# Tweets with "Media" inside

Tags: twitter

I see some tweets have some kind of HTML embedded. How is it possible to do this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like tweets to kickstarter.com and meetup.com have embedded HTML; there are probably other sites that do this, too.

Comment: Yes, there are. I want to know how the do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly is a list of hardcoded partnerships, as @dtt101 suggested.

**Evidence:** here's a list of partners *as taken from their javascript source* (the js file with "hogan-more" in it, e.g. at [`t1-hogan-more-en-201203071014.js`](https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/b/1/bundle/t1-hogan-more-en-201203071014.js) ):

**edit:** updated with domain names from the source

- Amazon: `www.amazon.com`
- AolVideo: `http://www.aol.com`
- Apple: `http://itunes.apple.com`
- BlipTV: `blip.tv`
- CNN: `http://cnn.com`
- DailyBooth: `dailybooth.com`
- DeviantArt: `http://deviantart.com`
- Dipdive: `http://dipdive.com`
- Etsy: `http://etsy.com`
- Facebook: `https://facebook.com` or `http://facebook.com`
- Flickr: `https://secure.flickr.com` or `http://www.flickr.com`
- Foursquare: `www.foursquare.com`
- GoogleVideo: `http://video.google.com`
- Gowalla: `www.gowalla.com`
- Hulu: `http://www.hulu.com`
- Instagram: `instagr.am`
- JustinTV: `http://justin.tv`
- Kickstarter: `kickstarter.com`
- Kiva: `http://www.kiva.org`
- Livestream: `http://www.livestream.com`
- Lockerz: `www.lockerz.com`
- Meetup: `www.meetup.com`
- MSNBC: `http://msnbc.com`
- MTV: `http://mtv.com`
- NHL: `http://www.nhl.com`
- Photobucket: `http://photobucket.com`
- Photozou: `http://photozou.jp`
- Plancast: `plancast.com`
- Rdio: `rdio.com`
- SlideShare: `http://slideshare.com`
- Twitgoo: `http://twitgoo.com`
- TwitPic: `twitpic.com`
- Twitter: `twitter.com`

  - CopiedTwimg: `twitter.com`
  - Twimg: `twitter.com`
- TwitVid: `www.twitvid.com`
- Ustream: `http://ustream.tv`
- Vevo: `http://vevo.com`
- Vimeo: `vimeo.com`
- WallStreetJournal: `http://online.wsj.com`
- WashingtonPost: `http://washingtonpost.com`
- WhoSay: `www.whosay.com`
- With: `https://with.me` or `http://with.me`
- WordPress: `wordpress.com`
- YFrog: `yfrog.com`
- Youtube: `www.youtube.com`

Comment: Well, it seems there is impossible to find any official reference online, but this evidence seems proof enough. Thanks for the research!

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.twitter.com/blog/photo-upload-api tells you how it works. There is an API which you can use to attach photos to tweets.

Comment: But this is not just a photo. This is also text, and some html

Comment: Apologies - my understanding of that is that it is not available via the public API's and requires some kind of content partnership with Twitter.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm somehow?

Comment: Sorry I can't find any other evidence than the lack of documentation!

Answer (score 0):

It's based on the [oembed](http://oembed.com/) standard, but I don't know how you get on the list of approved oembed providers.